# Merge lists with conditions in python

Tags: python, list, merge, conditional-statements

I've got this:

```
list_one = [[['id'], ['value']], [['id'], ['value2']] , [['id'], ['value3']]]
```

What i would like to have is :

```
list_two = [['id'], ['value'], ['value2'], ['value3']]
```

Based on the each id i have inside list_one.

Really appreciate the help.

Comment: not clear since you didn't provide an example with different `id` values

Comment: show first what you have tried

Comment: Is there a reason you keep using length-1 `list`s of `str`s instead of `str`s? If you could just use `str`, the answer will be a lot more elegant and your data will be easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
list_one = [[['id'], ['value']], [['id'], ['value2']] , [['id'], ['value3']]]

new_data = list(set(i[0] for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_one)))

final_list = list(map(lambda x: [x], sorted(new_data, key=len))) #must be casted to a list in Python3 because map returns a map instance.
```

Comment: @patrick Thanks for pointing that out. In Python3, it returns a map instance, although in Python2, it just returns a list. Since the OP did not tag python3.x, I did not cast the map to a list. However, I will note it.